# interior product of smooth vector field and k-form is smooth

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

**Exercise (Lee Smooth Manifolds Exercise 14.22):**
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$, $\omega$ a smooth differential $k$-form. $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$.
Show, that $i_X\omega$ (interior product) is smooth.

Please check if my solution is correct. This is my first time dealing with differential forms and I'm very unsure if I'm using them correctly.

**My solution:**
Let $(U,\varphi)$ be a chart in $M$. In these coordinates $$X = \sum X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^i}$$ $$\omega = \sum_I ' \omega^I d\varphi^I$$
To show that $i_X\omega\in \Omega^{k-1}(M)$ is smooth, it is enough to show that each coefficient $a^I$ of the summands in  $i_X\omega = \sum_I ' a^I d\varphi^I$ vary smoothly. For $J=(j_2,j_3,\dots, j_k)$
We have $$a^J(p) = i_X\omega \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_2}}\Bigg|_p, \dots , \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_k}}\Bigg|_p \right)=$$
$$=\sum_I ' \omega^I(p) d\varphi^I \left(X_p, \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_2}}\Bigg|_p, \dots , \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_k}}\Bigg|_p \right)=$$
$$=\sum_I ' \omega^I(p) \det
\begin{pmatrix}
d\varphi^{i_1}(X_p) & d\varphi^{i_1}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_2}}) & \cdots & d\varphi^{i_1}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_k}}) \\
d\varphi^{i_2}(X_p) & d\varphi^{i_2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_2}}) & \cdots & d\varphi^{i_2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_k}}) \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
d\varphi^{i_k}(X_p) & d\varphi^{i_k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_2}}) & \cdots & d\varphi^{i_k}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi^{j_k}}) 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Every entry of the determinant is smooth, hence we have shown $i_X\omega$ is smooth.

Comment: You can use that if $X=X^i\partial_i$, then $i_X(dx^{i_1}\wedge...\wedge dx^{i_k})=\sum_{l=1}^k(-1)^{l-1}X^l dx^{i_1}\wedge...\hat{dx^{i_l}}...\wedge dx^{i_k}$. So if you write down any $k-form$ $\omega$ in this basis, you can write $i_X\omega$ too and see that the components are smooth. (I hope I made myself clear).